# How do I include a required context in a ctools content type plugin?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I need to include a subject type as a required context for a ctools content type plugin? How and where is context set for the ctools plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the required context in the plugin definition array. Use the `'required context'` key and the `ctools_context_required` class.

Here are a few lines of stripped down code you can find in the [CTools Plugin Example module](http://drupalcode.org/project/ctools.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/ctools_plugin_example):

```
/**
 * Plugins are described by creating a $plugin array which will be used
 * by the system that includes this file.
 */
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('Simplecontext content type'),
  'description' => t('Simplecontext content type - works with a simplecontext context.'),
  'required context' => new ctools_context_required(t('Simplecontext'), 'simplecontext'),
);
```